# Unable to verify my domain with the "letsencrypt" verification tool

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to create a letsencrypt certificate for my domain. The webserver is working and is setup so that it returns the last segment of a path it's requested:

```
  my_domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/something ====>  something
```

However, when I'm running this:

```
  sudo ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/my_user/my_website -d my_website.com -d www.my_website.com
```

I get this error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. my_domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge [something1-something2.something3] != [something1-something2], www.my_domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: 

The client lacks sufficient authorization :: The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge [fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfd23232.something3] != [fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfddsfd23232]



Domain: www.my_website.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: The key authorization file from the server did not match
   this challenge
   [aaaaaa.bbbbb] != [aaaaaa]

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Why? Where did the part "bbbbb" and "something3" come from?